# CORS issue when running ionic project on android and browser

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, couchdb

I am having an ionic 3 project which is accessing remote url. However when i run the project on browser with "ionic serve" or on android emulator/device using "ionic cordova build android" command I am getting this following error :

Fetch API cannot load API URL. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I googled and found that this is CORS issue which occurs when one domain tries to access other domain, but the project works properly on other 2 machine on same network.
The database in use is couchDB.

Comment: How does CouchDB relate to the question? Is the CORS error only when talking to CouchDB, or when talking to the main app?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable specific origins on the server that are allowed the access it.
The Ionic Team has also written a nice summary about CORS related to Ionic: [Ionic Cors Documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/faq/cors)

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your external API have SSL protection means it's Https instead of Http. And if it is Https and still you are getting the error then use below plugin instead of fetch() or Angular HttpClient.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http